# Body is inexplicable wider than the content which is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have all my content, footer etc set to 100% so they will fit the width of the screen. For some reason though a horizontal scrollbar exists and when I scroll to the right the content remains the width of the screen but I can see a fraction of the body underneath all the content. Why could this be happening?

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e9g8s820/2/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        header
            <nav>
                nav
            </nav>
    </header>
<section id="intro">
</section>

<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futura';
    src:
    local('futura'),
    local('futuraextended'),
    url('_fonts/FuturaExtended.ttf')
    format('truetype');
}
html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    background:purple;
}
body {
    background:pink;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: 'futura', sans-serif;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:blue;
}
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;   
}
header {
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    background:pink;
}
#logo {
    height:200px;
    width:355px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../_images/ODA-logo-BW.png);
}
nav {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background:yellow;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    color:black;
    text-transform:lowercase;
}
nav ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
nav li {
    list-style:none;
    background:#adadad;
    padding-top:16.3px;
    padding-bottom:16.3px;
    padding-left:26px;
    font-size:26px;
}
nav li:hover {
    background:#bebebe; 
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
#intro {
    width:auto;
    height:850px;
    background-image:url(../_images/Sketch-2.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    background:red;
    opacity:.9;
}
```

Comment: `box-model` issue? - http://jsfiddle.net/e9g8s820/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your footer have `padding:10px;`

So the total width of footer is = `100% + 20px`

you can use `box-sizing:border-box` css property to prevent it with `width:100%`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e9g8s820/1/)** - Thanks to **@Paulie_D**

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you very much! I changed the padding to be top and bottom padding. That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Mary's answer is right. The issue is in the footer's padding. But you can also solve it by setting the padding to: `padding:10px 0;`

The first parameter is top and bottom, the second is right and left. http://jsfiddle.net/e9g8s820/3/